# Change the scene (load another FXML file)

Tags: javafx

I launch my application using this `Main.java` file:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class Main extends Application {

    Parent root;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/mainpage.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("Smart City - Main Page");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I also created a class named `ScreenChanger.java`:

```
package utils;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScreenChanger {

    public static void screenChanger(Event event, String path, String title) throws IOException{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(path));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle(title);
        stage.setMaximized(false);
        stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes I haven't that `Event` in my code when I want to switch between scenes. I would like to use something else instead of `Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();` in order to change the screen.

Comment: Pass a `Stage` to the method instead of an `Event`?

Comment: I don't use the `Stage` in my controllers anymore.

Comment: But you must be able to get a reference to the stage there somehow, using the same code you are currently using in the `screenChanger` method. I.e. you must have a reference to some node. Or just pass a node to the `screenChanger` method. It's hard to see what the problem is from the code and description you have provided.